# How do I correctly set the width of DataGridColumn

Tags: wpf, size

In a wpf window that has `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` I have a DataGrid with a column definition:

`<DataGridTemplateColum MinWidth="60"  ..>`

This looks fine, but when I resize and increase the width of the Window, this column stays at the specified width 60. It is the last column of the grid and I would like that this column fills the remaining space, so I added:

`<DataGridTemplateColum Width="*" MinWidth="60"  ..>`

Now when opening the window the column gets a huge width equal to both of my screen widths together  ... Is there a simple solution?

Comment: show us code, whats parent control to this grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width is working as expected, * will tell grid to take as much space as is available. Its the container of the grid which is not limiting the width of control. fix width of parent.

Comment: Yes it works, giving the Window itself a max+min-width works best for me.